# execute PHP script and get an update of process

Tags: php, exec

I need to write a script in PHP that read a list of XML and convert them in a  text file

I will add a button in my page that triggers

```
exec("xml2csv.php");
```

since i can have a lot of them i would like to give user feedback on process update, it can be a text feedback

kind of like javascript image upload with % update

i'm not sure is possible and how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you know the number of lines or bytes of XML you must parse, have your PHP script write to a file on the server the number of bytes (or lines) it has completed writing periodically throughout the scripts execution using `file_put_contents()`.

On the client side, using AJAX, poll the server for the contents of this file and display this result to the user every `x` seconds.  Using jQuery's `$.POST` would be good for this.

Comment: I guess i got what you are suggesting: i can count how many files i have and write some contents to a file that i'm going to update each time i finish processing a new one. On client i keep reading that file and update the info on the page. Not sure how to know that process is over

Comment: When the PHP script is aware that there are no more files to be processed, have it write to the same file the value `-1` or some value that it can check for.  The client-side can then look for this value to determine if that process is finished.  If you are happy with my answer, please tick it as the solution.  Good Luck.